# Prove the support of a real function is countable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is a problem from my real analysis homework. We are learning the countable sets, and have yet to reach uncountable sets.

> Let $f$ be a real function defined on $[0, 1]$. There exists a constant $M$, such that for each finite $n$, and $0 \le x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n \le 1$, we have
>
> $$
> |f(x_1) + f(x_2) + \cdots + f(x_n)| \le M.
> $$
>
> Prove $E \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{x \in [0, 1] : f(x) \ne 0\}$ is countable.

**My attempt**

I split $E$ into two parts,

$$
\begin{align}
E^{+} &\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{x \in [0, 1] : f(x) > 0\} \\
E^{-} &\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{x \in [0, 1] : f(x) < 0\}
\end{align}
$$

A classmate suggested considering $f(x) > \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x) \le \frac{1}{n}$ from $E^{+}$ separately, and proving for each $n$ both part have finite amount of elements, but I didn't gain much from her hint.

Another path I have taken is letting

$$
\begin{align}
E' &\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{x \in E : \exists \delta_x > 0, (x, x+\delta_x) \cap E = \varnothing \} \\
E'' &\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} E \setminus E'
\end{align}
$$

I can prove $E'$ is countable, but $E''$ is still tricky even though it contains less or equal elements than $E$.

Proof by contradiction didn't yield any significant result, either.

Comment: Terminological remark: usually, the set $E$ you define is not called the support, but rather its *closure* is. For instance, if you consider a function which is nonzero precisely at the rational numbers, then its support would be all of $[0,1]$. This doesn't impact the question because of how it's phrased, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: The trick is always the same; the nonzero reals can be partitioned into countably many sets each of which is strictly bounded away from zero. Remember this trick for real analysis and measure theory.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks for pointing that out! Initially I wasn't sure if it's the correct term, so I consulted [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)), and that appears to be the definition of a support? To quote, "In mathematics, the support of a real-valued function f is the subset of the domain containing those elements which are not mapped to zero."

Comment: Your classmate's suggestion might be slightly better as *considering $f(x) > \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x) \lt -\frac{1}{n}$ from $E$ separately, and proving for each $n$ both parts have a finite number of elements*

Comment: @Henry I could have misunderstood her point...

Comment: @Wojowu Remark on your remark: that's true when you're talking about continuous functions defined on topological spaces, but not for general functions (where the notion of closure is undefined).

Comment: @tparker I have seen this notion used for discontinuous functions on topological spaces well, but it is true that in a more general context this indeed doesn't make sense.

Comment: The reason behind Henry's comment is that the set $\{x:f(x) < 1/n\}$ does not need to be finite. For example, if $f(1/k) = 1/k$ for all $k$, then for any $n$, the set will include $1/k$ for every $k > n$, which is infinite. This misunderstanding may be why you didn't find her hint helpful, if it led you to trying to prove something false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A classmate suggested considering $f(x) > \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x) \le \frac{1}{n}$ from $E^{+}$ separately, and proving for each $n$ both part have finite amount of elements, ...

Your classmate is on the right track, but it suffices to show that there are (at most) finitely many points with  $f(x) > \frac{1}{n}$ in  $E^{+}$.

For each $n \in \Bbb N = \{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$ define 
$$
E^{+}_n = \left\{x \in [0, 1] : f(x) > \frac 1n \right\}
$$
Then $E^{+}_n$ has at most $nM$ elements. It follows that
$$
 E^{+} = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} E^{+}_n = \{x \in [0, 1] : f(x) > 0\}
$$
is countable (as the countable union of finite sets).

In the same way (or by applying the above argument to $-f$) it can be shown that $E^{-}$ is countable as well.

*Remark:* The domain of $f$ (in your case: the interval $[0, 1]$) is irrelevant for this conclusion. The same statement holds for a real-valued function $f$ defined on an arbitrary set $X$.